# Computing the homology groups of a quotient space of the sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I want to solve following question: Let $A$ denote the union of equatorial circle and the north pole on $S^2$. Let $X=S^2 / A$. Compute the homology groups of X. 
I calculated that $H_2(X) = \Bbb Z^2$, and all other homology groups are zero. Is this correct? If not, how do I solve this?

Comment: Can you calculate it using long exact sequence?

Comment: $H_1(X)$ is not trivial. How did you do your computation?

Comment: The space $X$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of $(S^1,s_0),\ (S_1^2,s_1),\ (S_2^2,s_2)$, that is, two $2$-spheres and one circle, with all pairs being good pairs.

Comment: I used to following long exact sequence: 0 --> H_2(A) --> H_2(S^2) --> H_2(X) --> H_1(A) --> H_1(S^2) --> H_1(X) --> H_0(A) --> H_0(S^2) --> H_0(X) --> 0 .                         For H_1(S^2) --> H_1(X) --> H_0(A) , since  H_1(S^2)=H_0(A)=0 , then H_1(X) sohuld be zero.

Comment: @MücahitMeral I presume you are taking reduced homology. Even then $\tilde{H_0}(A)$ is not trivial : as $A$ has two path components, ${H_0}(A) \cong \Bbb Z^2$ and since taking reduced homology throws out an extra copy of $\Bbb Z$ (recall $H_0(X) \cong \tilde{H_0}(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$), $\tilde{H_0}(A) \cong \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

As Stefan Hamcke has indicated in his comments, one can obtain $S^2/A$ step-by-step by first pinching the equator to a point to get $S^2 \vee S^2$ and then pinching the pole to the wedged point to have $S^2 \vee S^2 \vee S^1$. This is homotopy equivalent to our space.

Hence, $\widetilde{H_n}(S^2/A) \cong H_n(S^2 \vee S^1 \vee S^1)$ which is $\Bbb Z^2$ when $n = 2$ as you have proved and $\Bbb Z$ for $n = 1$, not trivial.

---

Alternatively, use the long exact sequence at $\widetilde{H_1}(S^2/A)$ : $$\cdots \to \widetilde{H_1}(S^2) \to \widetilde{H_1}(S^2/A) \to \widetilde{H_0}(A) \to \widetilde{H_0}(S^2) \to \cdots$$

$\widetilde{H_1}(S^2) \cong \widetilde{H_0}(S^2) \cong 0$, hence $\widetilde{H_1}(S^2/A) \cong \widetilde{H_0}(A)$. Since $A = S^1 \sqcup pt$, $\widetilde{H_0}(A) \cong \Bbb Z$. Thus, $H_1(S^2/A) \cong \Bbb Z$.

Similarly, we look at the long exact sequence at $\widetilde{H_2}(S^2/A)$ : $$\cdots \to \widetilde{H_2}(A) \to \widetilde{H_2}(S^2) \to \widetilde{H_2}(S^2/A) \to \widetilde{H_1}(A) \to \widetilde{H_1}(S^2) \to \cdots$$

$\widetilde{H_2}(A) \cong \widetilde{H_1}(S^2) \cong 0$, and $\widetilde{H_2}(S^2) \cong \widetilde{H_1}(A) \cong \Bbb Z$, so $\widetilde{H_1}(S^2/A)$ is an extension of $\Bbb Z$ by $\Bbb Z$, and indeed a split extension, which proves $\widetilde{H_2}(S^2/A) \cong \Bbb Z^2$ as you have done.